# Difference between ng-view and ng-template

Tags: angularjs, templates, view

I'm new to AngularJS. I've been developing in Titanium and now have shifted to Angular JS web app development.

Could anyone point out the precise difference between ng-view and ng-template?

If you could support the answer with actual code or a link that does so, it'll be great.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean `ng-include`? The `ng-template` can be used only as a type in script tag.

Answer (score 0):

ngView is a directive used to support the swapping of views when the route changes. I.E. #\members\homepage and #\members\guests.

[ngView Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView)

ngTemplate allows you to load the content of a  element into $templateCache, so that the template can be used by ngInclude, ngView, or directives.

[ngTemplate Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/script)

Answer (score 0):

ng-view content are automatically filled depending on the configuration of $routeProvider.

ng-include (ng-template does not exist, is only a fake mime type used to compile templates in memory) allows you to set explicitily the template to include es:

`<div class="slide-animate" ng-include="template.url"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

ng-view tag simply creates a place holder where a corresponding view (html or ng-template view) can be placed based on the configuration.

## ng-template

ng-template directive is used to create an html view using script tag. It contains "id" attribute which is used by $routeProvider to map a view with a controller.